# Linq SelectMany based on two properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Node Left {get; set;}
    public Node Right{get; set;}
}
```

Now I have tree that each node has a left and right node, and each of them has left and right nodes and so on.

I want to get `Name`s of all node in the tree, I couldn't do it with SelectMany.
I can do this in several ways like using a recursive function, but I'm really curious to know how is it done using Linq.

```
tree.SelectMany(x=> new List<Node> {x.Left, x.Right});
```

the above code just returns 2 Nodes (left and right nodes of the parent).

Comment: There's no builtin recursive LINQ method. So the best was if you just implement a recursive method yourself and call that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I actually did that and got what I wanted, but I was wondering if there is a way that I'm not aware of to do it with Linq and not callind another method.

Comment: You can find LINQ approaches on Stackoverflow. But they're pretty complex and often inefficient. Recursion and LINQ don't play well together, so my suggestion is to use your method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks a lot for your comment. as I said a have already done that, I was thinking that there is a simple way that I'm missing and I just asked the question for learning purpose and not for the project. so far I have chosen a good approach then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in LINQ is based on the interface [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1). So for your LINQ to work, you must translate your root `Node` tree into something that is `IEnumerable<Node>`. We can do this with an extension method.

```
public static class NodeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Node> ToEnumerable(this Node node)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Node>();
        if (node != null) stack.Push(node);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            yield return current;
            if (current.Left != null) stack.Push(current.Left);
            if (current.Right != null) stack.Push(current.Right);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have an `IEnumerable<Node>`, you can just do a simple `Select()`

```
foreach (var name in tree.ToEnumerable().Select(node => node.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

You do not need to use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) since your `Node` does not have an `IEnumerable<Node>` of child nodes, just left and right nodes. We use `SelectMany` when we need to coalesce many sequences into a single sequence.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found:

```
class Node
{
    public Node() {Children = new List<Node>();}

    public IEnumerable<Node> GetSubTree()
    {
         return Children.SelectMany(c => c.GetSubTree()).Concat(new[] {this});
    }

    public List<Node> Children {get;set;}
}

class Tree
{
    public Tree() {Roots = new List<Node>();}

    public IEnumerable<Node> GetAllNodes()
    {
         return Roots.SelectMany(root => root.GetSubTree());
    }

    List<Node> Roots {get;set;}
}
```

If I'm right about it: When calling `GetAllNodes()` from Tree class, it will get all nodes from each roots in the tree. Then you can get the names with this if you have an attribute called Name obviously:

```
List<string> Names = YourList.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: please note that we don't have a tree class, root is a node, with left & right nodes and so on. so tree itself is `typeof(Node)`.